# How to determine the directional behaviour of the magnetic vector potential?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, potential, vector-fields

I was wondering if someone could please help explain the directional behaviour of the magnetic  vector potential? I understand that the magnetic vector potential $A$ is perpendicular to $B=∇×A$ but can someone please help explain why this is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector potential is defined by ${\bf B}=\nabla \times {\bf A}$, but it is not uniquely defined. You can add the gradient of any scalar function to ${\bf A}$ and ${\bf B}$ will be unchanged.

That being true, then the vector potential could be in any direction.

Comment: In particular, the OP's assertion that the vector  potential is perpendicular to the magnetic field is not necessarily true.